# Можно ли написать hook-driver для функции WlanEnumInterfaces

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

Здравствуйте! Суть в том чтобы перехватить список сетей через wi-fi, исключить не нужные и оставить только свою. WlanEnumInterfaces - возвращает нужный список сетей. Думаю что надо писать драйвер, который перехватит эту функцию и возвратит мне нужный результат. Соб-но вопрос? правильный ли подход у меня? или быть может есть какое решение?

Comment: Так а что именно перехватывать тогда?..чтобы решить задачу?..